# What is shorting a asset that has negative price. Can anyone give me an example?

Tags: general

What is shorting a asset that has negative price.
Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Can you give an example of an asset with negative price?

Answer (score 3):

Three examples would be spreads, butterflies, and double-butterflies.  They can all have negative prices.  Reverse the sign of the quantity on all the legs and you're short the synthetic.

For example, the Jan-Feb calendar spread would buy 1 Jan and sell 1 Feb contract.  If you wanted to be short the spread, you would sell 1 Jan and buy 1 Feb contract.